# How to use $.each or alternative inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below(manually id keyed in) works as wanted. But I seriously cannot implement this in production as I wouldn't know the number of entry in the array. I noticed even with the below code, if undefined or null value returned it doesn't show up the entire results. So I need a single function that would iterate through each entry in the `globalStore.data` and each element inside div.morning, .afternoon and .evening.

Can't I simply write as following, where [i] represent the number of entry in the for loop;But this why wouldn't work? Is it because $.each cannot be used within for loop.Is there any other way of iterating within each element of div .morning, .afternoon and .evening?

```
 var arr = globalStore.data[i].morning;
 var arr2 = globalStore.data[i].afternoon;
 var arr3 = globalStore.data[i].evening;

    $("div.evening_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+" span").each(function(){if(arr_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
```

I also tried calling this function within for loop:

```
colorMe(globalStore.data[i].morning, globalStore.data[i].UUID);
```

//this function is placed outside of for loop separetely.

```
    function colorMe(param, param3)
    {
        console.log("DAY "+param);//this prints all the days unique to id correctly
        console.log("user "+param3);//this prints all the unique id correctly

//But when it comes to using $.each again, it doesn't return anything.

        var arr = param;
        $("div.morning_"+param3+" span").each(function() {
                    if(arr.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                      //$(this).css("color","#ff0000");
                      console.log("TEXT "+$(this).text());

                    }
                });

    }
```

//This works

```
 $(function()
    {

    var globalStore = {};
    globalStore.data = [];
    var data;
    $.when(
    $.get('/search/show_all_tutors.php',function(data){globalStore.data = globalStore.data.concat(data);console.log(data)},"json")
).then(function() {
for (i = 0; i < globalStore.data.length; i++) {


/*long procedural code starts*/
 var user = globalStore.data[0].UUID;
           var user2 = globalStore.data[1].UUID;
            var user3 = globalStore.data[2].UUID;
             var user4 = globalStore.data[3].UUID;
              var user5 = globalStore.data[4].UUID;
               var user6 = globalStore.data[5].UUID;
                var user7 = globalStore.data[6].UUID;
                 var user8 = globalStore.data[7].UUID;



         var arr = globalStore.data[0].morning;
         var arr2 = globalStore.data[1].morning;
         var arr3 = globalStore.data[2].morning;
         var arr4 = globalStore.data[3].morning;
         var arr5 = globalStore.data[4].morning;
         var arr6 = globalStore.data[5].morning;
         var arr7 = globalStore.data[6].morning;
         var arr8 = globalStore.data[7].morning;


         var arr_af = globalStore.data[0].afternoon;
         var arr2_af = globalStore.data[1].afternoon;
         var arr3_af = globalStore.data[2].afternoon;
         var arr4_af = globalStore.data[3].afternoon;
         var arr5_af = globalStore.data[4].afternoon;
         var arr6_af = globalStore.data[5].afternoon;
         var arr7_af = globalStore.data[6].afternoon;
         var arr8_af = globalStore.data[7].afternoon;

         var arr_ev = globalStore.data[0].evening;
         var arr2_ev = globalStore.data[1].evening;
         var arr3_ev = globalStore.data[2].evening;
         var arr4_ev = globalStore.data[3].evening;
         var arr5_ev = globalStore.data[4].evening;
         var arr6_ev = globalStore.data[5].evening;
         var arr7_ev = globalStore.data[6].evening;
         var arr8_ev = globalStore.data[7].evening;



        $("div.morning_"+user+" span").each(function(){if(arr.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
         $("div.morning_"+user2+" span").each(function(){if(arr2.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
          $("div.morning_"+user3+" span").each(function(){if(arr3.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
           $("div.morning_"+user4+" span").each(function(){if(arr4.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
            $("div.morning_"+user5+" span").each(function(){if(arr5.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
             $("div.morning_"+user6+" span").each(function(){if(arr6.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
              $("div.morning_"+user7+" span").each(function(){if(arr7.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
               $("div.morning_"+user8+" span").each(function(){if(arr8.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});

      $("div.afternoon_"+user+" span").each(function(){if(arr_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
         $("div.afternoon_"+user2+" span").each(function(){if(arr2_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
          $("div.afternoon_"+user3+" span").each(function(){if(arr3_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
           $("div.afternoon_"+user4+" span").each(function(){if(arr4_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
            $("div.afternoon_"+user5+" span").each(function(){if(arr5_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
             $("div.afternoon_"+user6+" span").each(function(){if(arr6_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
              $("div.afternoon_"+user7+" span").each(function(){if(arr7_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
               $("div.afternoon_"+user8+" span").each(function(){if(arr8_af.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});



        $("div.evening_"+user+" span").each(function(){if(arr_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
         $("div.evening_"+user2+" span").each(function(){if(arr2_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
          $("div.evening_"+user3+" span").each(function(){if(arr3_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
           $("div.evening_"+user4+" span").each(function(){if(arr4_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
            $("div.evening_"+user5+" span").each(function(){if(arr5_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
             $("div.evening_"+user6+" span").each(function(){if(arr6_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
              $("div.evening_"+user7+" span").each(function(){if(arr7_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});
               $("div.evening_"+user8+" span").each(function(){if(arr8_ev.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {$(this).css("color","#26F525");}});     
/*ends*/

$("#contents").append("<div class='small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-left'> Availability:</div><div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left day morning_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"' id='"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"'>Morning: <span class='Mon'>M </span><span class='Tue'>T </span><span class='Wed'>W </span><span class='Thrs'>T </span><span class='Fri'>F </span><span class='Sat'>S </span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left day afternoon_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"' id='"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"'>Afternoon: <span class='Mon'>M </span><span class='Tue'>T </span><span class='Wed'>W </span><span class='Thrs'>T </span><span class='Fri'>F </span><span class='Sat'>S </span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left day evening_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"' id='"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"'>Evening: <span class='Mon'>M </span><span class='Tue'>T </span><span class='Wed'>W </span><span class='Thrs'>T </span><span class='Fri'>F </span><span class='Sat'>S </span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div>");
}
});
});
```

Comment: show html code specially which have div.morning_"+param3+" span"

Comment: Can you please create fiddle so i will sort out our code

Comment: @ShailendraSharma, HTML is append via jquery is shown in my post within for loop

Comment: @ShailendraSharma, this is the correct fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/yeLkqsd6/1/

Comment: @ShailendraSharma, updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yeLkqsd6/2/

Comment: @Mitul i created the fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/yeLkqsd6/2/

Comment: what you have in globalStore please update this in you question

Comment: all fiddles' have syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

i have one solution for you, i am not using `$.each` but you don't need write repetitive code for change color

you can call a function in your success block of promise

```
.then(function() {
for (i = 0; i < globalStore.data.length; i++) {

CheckAvailability(globalStore.data[i].UUID,globalStore.data[0].morning,globalStore.data[i].afternoonon,globalStore.data[i].evening)

//here your other code
}
```

define a function like this

```
function CheckAvailability(User,morning,afternoon,evening){
$("div.morning_"+User+" span").each(function(){
      if(morning.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {
       $(this).css("color","#26F525");
    }
});


$("div.afternoon_"+User+" span").each(function(){
      if(afternoon.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {
       $(this).css("color","#26F525");
    }
});

$("div.evening_"+User+" span").each(function(){
      if(evening.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {
       $(this).css("color","#26F525");
    }
});
}
```

[here the fiddle with single value](http://jsfiddle.net/yeLkqsd6/7/)

Comment: I created a function similar to yours..it works but only not showing the value for the last item in the array..Will sort it out

Comment: change condition i < globalStore.data.length;  to  i <= globalStore.data.length;  in your for loop

Comment: call CheckAvailability() function after append html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the json object like bellow and then ut will work for you.

```
var users =  [{
            name: 'aa11',
            morning: 'Tue,Wed,Thrs,Mon',
            afternoon: 'Fri,Sat',
            evening: 'Tue,Mon'
        },
        {
            name: 'bb22',
            morning: 'Tue,Wed,Mon',
            afternoon: 'Fri,Mon',
            evening: 'Fri,Mon'
        },
        {
            name: 'cc33',
            morning: 'Tue,Wed,Fri',
            afternoon: 'Sun,Sat',
            evening: ''
        }
    ];

for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    morning = users[i].morning.split(",");
    afternoon = users[i].afternoon.split(",");
    evening = users[i].evening.split(",");
    user = users[i].name;

    $("div.morning_" + user + " span").each(function () {

        if (morning.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {
            $(this).css("color", "#26F525");
        }
    });
    $("div.afternoon_" + user + " span").each(function () {
        if (afternoon.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {
            $(this).css("color", "#26F525");
        }
    });
    $("div.evening_" + user + " span").each(function () {
        if (evening.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {
            $(this).css("color", "#26F525");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

called a function from for loop

```
colorMe(globalStore.data[i].morning,globalStore.data[i].afternoon,globalStore.data[i].evening, globalStore.data[i].UUID);
```

//defined a function

```
function colorMe(param,param_af,param_eve, param2)
    {

        /*console.log("DAY "+param);
        console.log("user "+param2);*/
       /* console.log("K+ "+k);*/

        userarray.push(param2);
        //console.log("mY "+userarray[k]);
        dayarray.push(param);
        dayarray2.push(param_af);
        //console.log("afternoon "+dayarray2[k]);
        dayarray3.push(param_eve);
        console.log("evening "+dayarray3[k]);
        //console.log("Day "+dayarray[k]);
        //console.log("k="+ k);

        for(;data<k;data++)
        {
            //console.log("data="+ data);
        var arr = dayarray[data];
        var arr2 = dayarray2[data];
        var arr3 = dayarray3[data];
        $("div.morning_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                    if(arr.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                      $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                    }
                });

                $("div.afternoon_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                    if(arr2.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                      $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                    }
                });
                $("div.evening_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                    if(arr3.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                      $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                    }
                });

        }
        k++;

    }
```